# What does "Invalid clnors in this fan!" mean?

Tags: command-line

When I open or render a frame of one specific scene, I have several messages in the Console with the note "`Invalid clnors in this fan!`"

[image]

This message also shows up when I try command line rendering.

I'm having problems rendering this and other scenes from the same project.

What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 6):

Clnors stands for Custom Loop Normals.

This happens when clnors are not equal to each other where they should (would have to see the geometry), this message is printed and they are all replaced with their average value to be equal.

Comment: Ok, but what are Custom Loop Normals anyway? It's a bad thing receiving this warning? If so, is there a way to correct this?

Comment: @AntonioBuch This is only what I got from the source code where this message gets printed, It's not that well commented. The file is in *source/blender/bmesh/intern/bmesh_mesh.c*. You would probably have to ask a developer about this and how big an issue it is.

Answer (score 6):

Since I had the same message in the console with my processor going crazy, and I haven't found more information about that here, I answere this old question.
In my case it was related to custom split normals data:

[image: custom split normals data]

I've had a problem with imported Evermotion scene. Some objects had bad custom normals and my cpu was going overload.

Things went ok after clearing custom normals from the object.

Blender 2.78a Windows7 x64

Comment: Thanks for the response, it could be a solution. Unfortunately I cannot remember the project in which I had that problem. Let me check the date, maybe I can find the scenes to test it.